# remove html line break between <li> tags with php (or python)

Tags: php, python, regex, html-parsing

I have a large data set of html text, and I frequently find unnecessary, and sometimes multiple, `<br>` line breaks within `<li>` tags.

For example:

```
<li>Some string here<br></li><br><li>Another string here<br><br></li><br>
```

I would like to remove these `<br>` that appear between `<li>` and `</li>` but preserve everything else, including `<br>` outside of `<li>` tags. The text above would become:

```
<li>Some string here</li><br><li>Another string here</li><br>
```

What is the regular expression for doing this with preg_replace() in php (or re.sub() in python)?

Comment: *"What is the regex?"* How much you gonna pay me?

Comment: Are you using PHP to put the content in the li tags?

Comment: @AaronMiller No, just trying to remove from raw text. I'm not inserting anything.

Comment: [lxml](http://lxml.de/lxmlhtml.html#cleaning-up-html) module may not do exactly what you want, but it is generally helpful for cleaning up html.

Comment: you do **NOT** use regexes to mangle html. you use DOM.

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags) accepted answer.

Comment: I suggest you to use a `HTML` parser to find leading and trailing `<br>`s within `<li>` tags. The suggested regexes here may work with you example, but be aware that `HTML` is not a Regular Language and can't be parsed with Regular Expressions generally!

Comment: I'm not trying to render with html. I'm just treating the html as flat text to do a batch analysis that clusters on certain tags. This isn't for creating valid html code.

Comment: @user1521440: "I'm just treating the html as flat text" and that's the problem.  HTML is not flat text.  Use an HTML parser.  http://htmlparsing.com/ has examples for both PHP and Python.  BeautifulSoup in Python is especially powerful.

Answer (score 2):

Using [PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm) you can achieve this easily (just like jQuery)

```
include('simple_html_dom.php');
$html = str_get_html('<li>Some string here<br></li><br><li>Another string here<br><br></li><br>');
foreach($html->find('li br') as $br){
    $br->outertext='';
}
echo $html;
```

The output will be

```
<li>Some string here</li><br>
<li>Another string here</li><br>
```

Answer (score 0):

replacing `(<br>)+</li>` with `</li>` will take care of line breaks at the end of the li content at least, which may be good enough for you. Otherwise, as `<li>`s sometimes contain other `<li>`s, you may have a pretty difficult task in front of you that cannot easily be solved with regexp (and maybe cannot be solved with regexp alone at all), see the accepted answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/546433/regular-expression-to-match-outer-brackets).